# I cant install the forecast package

Tags: r, install.packages

I have installed the latest version of R but I can't install the package `forecast`. When I try, I get an error:

> No such file or directory Error in install.packages : cannot open the
>   connection

Comment: Looks like it can't reach a CRAN mirror. Try setting a new one.

Comment: This would happen if you're behind a firewall too. You may need to download the source file of it directly from the web. I've had to do it on multiple occasions and is super simple to pull off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be of use:

It looks to me like you need to change your CRAN access mechanism in RStudio. I am not sure which OS you are running RStudio on, so here is a breakdown of the how by OS. I hit the same issue on Centos 7, and this is how I resolved it.

Windows

```
utils::setInternet2(TRUE)
options(download.file.method = "internal")
```

Note that `setInternet2(TRUE)` is the default value in RStudio however is not for R GUI. If you don’t want to use `setInternet2(TRUE)` on Windows then the only other way to configure secure downloads is to have the `“wget”` or `“curl”` utility on your PATH as described for OS X and Linux below.

OS X

```
options(download.file.method = "curl")
```

Linux

```
options(download.file.method = "wget")
```

Note that the `“curl”` and `“wget”` methods will work on any platform so long as the requisite binary is in the system PATH. The recommendations above are based on the fact that “curl” is included in OS X and `“wget”` is included in most Linux distributions.

## Proposed Solution

I use this on Centos 7, to reconfigure my CRAN setup. I have this added to my `.Rprofile`, you can try by running at the R prompt.

```
options(download.file.method = "wget") # <- for MacOSX use curl

local({
     r<- getOption("repos");
     r["CRAN"] <-"https://cran.rstudio.com/"
     options(repos=r)
}) 

> install.packages("forecast")
```

## Explanation:

When R transfers files over HTTP (e.g. using the install.packages or download.file function) a download method is chosen based on the download.file.method option. There are several methods available and the default behaviour if no option is explicitly specified is to use R’s internal HTTP implementation. In many circumstances, this internal method will not support HTTPS connections so you’ll need to override the default.

ref: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897-Secure-Package-Downloads-for-R

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I've dig everywhere still cant find the way to change the package management>

Comment: @hxnnx Great - happy to help. Can you please mark as answered (selected and tick answer) if the code helped solve your problem.

Comment: Forecast is not function properly. How ?

Comment: Can you create a new question and post the output of the following?
> R
> sessionInfo()
Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LC_TIME = "C", LANGUAGE = "en")
library("tools")
testInstalledBasic("both")
testInstalledPackages(scope = "base")
testInstalledPackages(scope = "recommended")
testInstalledBasic("internet")